# Как предварительно оценить размер GIF файла?

Tags: imagemagick, оптимизация, изображения, компрессия

Строим веб приложение по работе с видео. Одна из функций — экспорт фрагмента в виде анимационного GIF'а на [Imgur](http://imgur.com/). Там есть лимит: макс. 2Мб может весить GIF-анимация.

Сначала вывожу все кадры видео как серию PNG нужного размера кадра, без компрессии.
Затем собираю в GIF с помощью [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/). Процесс не мгновенный.

Для максимизации качества при потолке размера файла хочется приблизиться максимально близко к этому потолку.

Пока просто пробую. Делаю рендер, смотрю размер файла. Если есть запас — чуть улучшаю параметры. Так несколько итераций, пока не случится перебор по размеру GIF'а. Варьировать можно частоту (кол-во) кадров и глубину цвета. Примерно, из опыта/попыток известно, какое кол-во кадров можно впихнуть при 256 цветах. С этого значения начинаю.

Плохо, что приходится гнать несколько рендеров — это занимает время и ресурсы сервера.

Поэтому **вопрос**: как, не генеря собственно GIF, можно быстро и точно прикинуть размер GIF'а с разными настройками?

Ведь многое зависит от самих изображений: их содержания (плоский цвет или тв-шум), гистограммы цветов. Не факт, что это возможно, но вдруг, есть идеи?

Как вариант пока собираюсь тестово рендерить уменьшенные копии GIF'ов: скажем, 1/4 от реального размера, и по ним сравнивать размеры файлов, и тогда уже считать "рабочий", размером 400*225. Но вдруг есть более умный способ?

Comment: не совсем ответ на Ваш вопрос, но присмотритесь также к минификации png (кадров) - есть возможность делать это без потерь качества картинки, начать можно отсюда - https://github.com/imgo/imgo